# Trying to save just one page of a document

Tags: save, 1c

I want to save just one page of a document but when i try to save it doesn't give me any option and it saves all 15 pages in just one document. Is there any way to do select only one page?

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar code. Maybe this will help you.

```
Procedure SaveDocument(ObjectDocument) Export 
    
    // Printing the first page
    SpreadsheetDocument = New SpreadsheetDocument;
    SpreadsheetDocument.FitToPage           = ObjectDocument.FitToPage;
    SpreadsheetDocument.PageOrientation     = ObjectDocument.PageOrientation;
    SpreadsheetDocument.PrintScale          = ObjectDocument.PrintScale;
    SpreadsheetDocument.PageSize            = ObjectDocument.PageSize;
    
    For counter = 1 To ObjectDocument.TableHeight Do
        
        SpreadsheetDocument.Clear();
        SpreadsheetDocument.Put(ObjectDocument.GetArea(1,1,counter,ObjectDocument.TableWidth));
        
        If SpreadsheetDocument.PageCount() > 1 Then 
            
            EndOfFirstPage = counter - 1;
            Break;
        EndIf;
        
    EndDo;
    
    Output(ObjectDocument.GetArea(1,1, EndOfFirstPage, ObjectDocument.TableWidth))
    
EndProcedure
```